# Is there a way to use a cached image from a url as a placeholder of the FadeInImage.memoryNetwork or another widget which does the same thing?

Tags: flutter, caching, networkx, placeholder

I have a flutter app with a detail page with the main fadeinimage widget and many small images on the bottom of it.  When the user taps one of the small images, the main image changes to a bigger version of the small image, I was hoping that when the user taps the small image, it could be used as the placeholder of the large image because it has already been loaded and shows that photo till the big picture is loaded.  Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to checkout the package https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image